# Вопрос про шаблонные функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template <int>
int foo()
{
    int y=9;
    return y;
}

template <float>
float foo()
{
    float y=9;
    return y;
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы по одному имени функции можно было работать с разными типами, поэтому сделала шаблонной. Но выскакивает ошибка.
Здесь вариант с классом дроби.

```
template<int>
int foo()
{
    int y=9;
    return y;
}

template <class Ratio>
Ratio foo()
{
    Ratio res(5,6);//здесь вместо конструктора, который есть, пишет про лист инициализации, и также ошибка
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Вам следует ещё раз почитать про шаблоны, в частности функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
T foo()
{
    T y = 9;
    return y;
}
```

Вот так как-то... :) А если для `Ratio` надо что-то отдельное, то после этого

```
template<>
Ratio foo()
{
    Ratio res(5,6);
    return res;
}
```

Но общий вариант с `typename T` — должен быть объявлен до спциализации.

Comment: Да не, у меня есть класс матриц, который в свою очередь может состоять из дробей, и из обычных чисел. Я хочу ввести такую функцию, чтобы элементы матрицы не замисимо от типа заполнялись рандомными числами, то есть я просто , на пример, делаю так arr[i][j]=rand<t>; а это уже для каждого типа функция разная, тк в одном случае просто внутрии нее буду вызывать std::rand, а в др заполнять рандомными числитель и знаменатель. Поэтому хотела сделать по по одному имени, но с разными шаблонами

Comment: А вот теперь все стало совсем непонятно...